# Relative URL redirection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Main page URLs are like as follows:
https://www.example.com/fr/en/home and https://www.example.com/fr/sa/home

Both of these URLs have been rewrite to one of my landing page https://www.example.com/fr/lpfr.aspx successfully.

Now I have a problem while redirection from **landing page to signin page**. My landing page contains signin page link. That link should redirect to https://www.example.com/fr/en/sign or https://www.example.com/fr/sa/signin depending on URL which is currently loaded in browser. What code could be written so that href on signin link becomes like `href = "~/fr/en/signin"` or `href = "~/fr/sa/signin "` depending on URL which is currently loaded in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Resources if you doesn't, for multi language and make routing pages by using resources attribute like `@Resources.Language` that will render your variable to current language that will do this for you easy, or you can use `Request.RawUrl` and concatenation with your string, I Hope that helps, congrats and waiting your response any time.

Comment: if you give screenshot of code or some snippet, I will try to write the specific code solution.

Comment: Actually their is a single landing page and on that landing page I want the links to be framed as per the URL in browser. For ex. if browser has loaded `fr/en/home` then I want signin Link on that page to be `fr/en/signin` . This all to be done on client side.

Comment: @RaghvenderKataria so you doesn't use localization multi languages, in this case you can get Current page url With `string currentUrl=@Request.RawUrl` and then use `string signInUrl =currentUrl.Remove(currentUrl.LastIndexOf('/')) + "signin"`, hope that helps , congrats.